# Remove blank lines Powershell output

Tags: powershell, blank-line

I wrote a script to find GID's in AD, this is working fine, the issue I'm having is filtering out the blank (null lines)

```
 $searcher=[adsisearcher]"(objectCategory=user)"
$result = $searcher.FindAll()
$result | Select-Object @{Name="DN";Expression+{$_.properties.distinguishedname}},@{Name="gid";Expression={$_.properties.gidnumber }} |Sort-Object -Property gid
```

Comment: Try adding a `Where` statement like `| Where {$_.someproperty -ne $null}`

Comment: What do you mean by "blank line"? You select several properties from the objects your search returned. Do you want to omit objects where all properties are `$null`? Objects where at least one of them is `$null`? Objects where one particular property is `$null`?

Comment: Similar to Brocks comment, add a `| ? {$_}` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it odd that you would be getting blank lines with that code. Can't think of a scenario where the `distinguishedname` of a user is null. The one issue with your code that I do see might just be a typo in your first calculated expression:

```
@{Name="DN";Expression+{$_.properties.distinguishedname}}
```

should instead be

```
@{Name="DN";Expression={$_.properties.distinguishedname}}
```

However that should have just made a syntax error that would be easily caught before execution.

## Filtering Blanks

A real easy PowerShell way to deal with this is to use a simple `Where-Object` clause. For argument sake lets say that the `GID` could be empty/null.

```
$result | Select-Object @{Name="DN";Expression={$_.properties.distinguishedname}},@{Name="gid";Expression={$_.properties.gidnumber }} | Where-Object{$_.GID} | Sort-Object -Property gid
```

A null or empty value evaluates to False in PowerShell. `Where-Object{$_.GID}` will only allow objects with a populated property for `GID` to pass as output. You will get similar results from string static methods as well. These would also add readability to your code.

```
... | Where-Object{[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.GID)} | ...
```

There is also `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score -1):

Sort Object has a -unique property which will remove *most* of the blank lines, all but one as you have guessed. You could also pipe to a

```
where-object -ne '`n'
```

or something similar, let me know if I should elaborate that.